Trying to use firebase auth but cause preview crash
I tried to use FirebaseAuth to check if the currentUser is logged in but it just make my app crashed all the time. I tried to clear build but it doesn't work. Restart the xcode also doesn't work. Is there any way to solve this problem
My code for content view
import SwiftUI
import SwiftfulRouting
import FirebaseAuth

struct ContentView: View {
   // @StateObject var viewModel: Router

    var body: some View {
        if AuthService.shared.isLogin() {
            TabPage()
        }
        else{
            InitPage()
        }
    }
}

This is my AuthService
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth


@MainActor
class AuthService{
    static let shared = AuthService()
    
    func login(withEmail: String, password: String) async throws{
        print("Enter")
    }
    
    func createUser(withEmail email :String, password: String, reenteredPassword:String, username:String) async throws{
        do{
            let result = try await Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email , password: password)
            print(result)
        }catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func isLogin() -> Bool{
        do{
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                print("Auth here")
                return true
            }
            
            print("Log in")
            return false
        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

This is how I configured my firebase
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    print("Colors application is starting up. ApplicationDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.")
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
  }
}

@main
struct MealMeApp: App {  
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

Really not sure why my preview crashed.
Here is the error report I've got from xcode


"but it just make my app crashed all the time." Is there an error message in console when this happen?

@Larme There is not really an error message shown. All it  shows is "Preview Crashed" with a red "x" in the center of the screen.

You’ll get  popup that says “report” click on it and you’ll see a crash report.

@loremipsum I've got the error report, it says Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT). I'm not really sure what kind of this error.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/sigabrt

Honestly the issues likely has to do with the app not being fully running in preview. But look further down. I personally hide firebase behind a protocol and mock things for preview. It can get very expensive making calls to firebase during development. But that is a much more complex solution.
